# GC optimization: for vs foreach

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection

I've been trying to optimize some of my code, and ive reached a strange conclusion regarding fors.

In my testcase ive created a new project with main activity. The activity initializes a List of 500 objects, runs an explicit GC and starts the thread. The thread loops the function doCalculations.

this.objects is a list of 500 MyObject, previous is MyObject, value is int. The function logics hold no logic, they are just there to do stuff. The difference is in the inner for.

function1

```
public void doCalculations()
{
    for(MyObject o : this.objects)
            for(int i=0; i<this.objects.size(); i++)
                if(this.objects.get(i) == o)
                    o.value = this.objects.get(i).value;
}
```

function 2

```
public void doCalculations()
{
    for(MyObject o : this.objects)
            for(MyObject o2 : this.objects)
                if(o2 == o)
                    o.value = o2.value;
}
```

With function 2 GC is called every ~10 secs on my nexus s, freeing ~1.7MB.

With function 1 GC is never to be seen.

Why is that?

Comment: Isn't `==` just checking if the two objects are the same instance? Since they are the same instance, then `value` (and every thing else) is already equal...

Comment: I guess it's a bunch of `this.objects.iterator()`s that's being collected in #2.

Comment: @GrailsGuy A GC each 10 seconds is not micromanaging (unless the numbers are way elswhere in the real app).

Comment: Is there a reason that you are assigning a value from an instance to itself? Or are the internals of the loop irrelevant to the question about the loop itself.

Comment: What does this exactly mean? Does function2 or function1 take more memory? Notice, that if "objects" is LinkedList function 2 will be much more faster since random acces as objects.get(i) is much slower tahn using iterator as in foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry my bad for putting useless logic in fors. Its just for test purpose, and yes function 2 takes more memory because, appereantly, of iterators.

Comment: If performance is an issue I would avoid brute force searching of a list of 500 items.  I would use an index type like Map as well or instead of List. A lookup on a Map might not create any garbage (unless some auto-boxing has to occur in which case, use trove4j)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One creates an iterator, the other doesn't.

Is the GC actually a bottleneck in your application?  (It seems unlikely.  Many devs, myself included, would consider the readability benefit to outweigh a few microseconds of GC.)

That said, your entire loop is a no-op anyway.

Comment: Yes, it causes fps drops. So all those iterators are filling the heap?

Comment: That's correct, though I'd still be very surprised if this alone were causing any measurable performance issues.  Have you profiled to demonstrate that this loop is causing most of that garbage?  Is the FPS drop significant?  (And since this loop is a no-op anyway, you might as well delete it.)

Comment: Yes the loop makes no sense on purpose. It was just a test to see if the fors were behaving like i thought they would.

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid allocations during animation on Android.  This will hopefully be improved someday with better handling of short-lived temporary objects.  Ideally, in the current system, the concurrent GC would do all the work in a separate thread and the animation-thread's pause would be brief enough to not cause a visible disturbance, but that's not always the case in practice.

Comment: Fwiw, I've seen iterators in tight loops also cause noticeable (though not huge) performance hits. Don't necessarily believe all the coolaid that they're so close to free that you can think of them as essentially free. :)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that' because the inner for-loop creates an Iterator for each run of the outer for loop (in *function 2*).
This Iterator-instances are not created in *function 1*